# Replace form with Results after ajaxSubmit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am trying to dynamically replace a form with the results from the POST response. For this example, I am closing an announcement and would like the "Close Announcement" submit button / form to be replaced by simply "Announcement Closed" upon its success. The POST works fine and I can return the results as expected, just not in the specific div.

I figure the $post->ID would be a unique ID so I can remove that div, but I don't know how to pass it to the ajaxSubmit function.

```
<div id="<?php echo $post->ID;?>">
  <form action="" method="post" id="openclose">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post->ID;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ocVehicleWanted"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="oc" value="close">
    <button type="submit" style="padding:1px;background-color:#c41f1f;" >Close Announcement</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is my current jQuery, the only portion that is not working is the .html(data) for replacing the form data in the $post->ID div. This current code replaces all of the form divs that were output for the page. I have 25 of these per page.

```
jQuery('#openclose').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

var vehicledata = jQuery(this).serialize();
jQuery.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
data: vehicledata,
success:function(data){
jQuery("#openclose").html(data);
}
});

return false;
}
```

Comment: You should have `class` selector instead of `id` in this case. Use `$(this)` in callback function..

Comment: @RayonDabre understand what you are suggesting but `$(this)` in callback doesn't have the element context

Comment: @charlietfl, There are various ways to have that context. One approach is suggested by you and another by me ;P

Comment: and a third is `context` property of ajax options. I was only commenting based on no context comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ID's to class since ID's must be unique in a page

You can replace the whole form several ways by starting with `this` and a traverse to `parent()` or by using `replaceWith()` as well as several other ways

```
function ajaxSubmit() {
    var $form = jQuery(this);// cache form as jQuery object
    var vehicledata = $form.serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: vehicledata,
        success: function(data) {
            // replace form parent html
            $form.parent().html(data);
            // or replaace form element
            $form.replaceWith(html);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This solved it, simple change to do that trick. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

> You must not have multiple `id` attributes having same `value` in a document.

You can use `class` selectors instead.

`.bind()` will provide the `this` context in the function expression which will be used once the function is invoked.

Try this:

```js
jQuery('.openclose').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit() {

  var vehicledata = jQuery(this).serialize();
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: vehicledata,
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery(this).html(data);
    }.bind(this)
  });

  return false;
}
```

```html
<div id="<?php echo $post->ID;?>">
  <form action="" method="post" class="openclose">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $post->ID;?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ocVehicleWanted" />
    <input type="hidden" name="oc" value="close">
    <button type="submit" style="padding:1px;background-color:#c41f1f;">Close Announcement</button>
  </form>
</div>
```